# How to write a sentence with several verbs associated to different objects?

Tags: translation, verbs

I have searched the internet for help on using several verbs in one sentence when they are connected with different objects and performed by different people, but every search comes back with an explanation of the て-form which is not quite the same thing. Every example of this form I have seen is used for listing verbs a single agent performed. What I have in mind, however, is something like this:

> The professor asked me to ask you to teach me about your research.

I have been trying an attempt at a translation of my own, but it is always so clumsy I'm not sure about it.

> 先生は私にあなたにあなたの研究について私に説明するように頼むように頼んだ。

This is confusing to me because, since the order of the words is not important, and since the particle に is used twice, it could mean that the teacher asked you to ask me to explain to you about your research.

Can you help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The professor asked me to ask you to teach me about your research.
>   先生は私にあなたにあなたの研究について私に説明するように頼むように頼んだ。

Your sentence is grammatically correct, but you're right that it's a bit clumsy.. I think it's probably because the subject changes too many times.. like, 先生 for 頼んだ, 私 for 頼む, あなた for 説明する..

I suggest using 「～してもらう」"to have someone do~~" and 「～よう(に(と))言われた」"I was told to do~~", so that the subject of the whole sentence doesn't change (ie. the subjects of してもらう and 言われる are both 私), like this:

> 私は、あなたの研究についてあなたに説明してもらうように、先生に言われました。
>   *lit.* I was told to have you explain your research by professor.

and you can omit the pronouns that are clear from the context, like this:

> 「あなたの研究について説明してもらうように、先生に言われました。」

(As you may know, it'd be more polite and normal to say 「[name] + さん/くん etc.」 instead of あなた.)

Alternatively, you can also say like this:

> 「[name]さんの研究について教えてもらいなさいと、先生に/から言われました。」
>   「研究について[name]さんに教えてもらうよう、先生に/から言われました。」
>   「[name]さんに研究について聞くように(と)、先生に/から言われました。」
>   etc...